# Is there a way to solve this

Tags: active-directory, bitlocker

```
$Computers = get-content "C:\ADMIN\SCRIPTS\BITLOCKER\LAPTOPS.txt"

foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
    if (Test-Connection -Cn $Computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)
    {  
        $bitID = manage-bde -protectors -get c: -Type recoverypassword -cn $Computer | findstr /i /r /c:"{*}"
        if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($bitID)))
            {
            $GUID = $bitID.Trim() -replace 'ID: ',''
            $pc = Get-ADComputer $Computer
            $dn = $pc.DistinguishedName
            $ldPath = "AD:\",$dn -join ""
            $ldObj = Get-ChildItem $ldPath | where {$_.objectClass -eq "msFVE-RecoveryInformation" } 
            #write-host $Computer' : '$GUID' - '$ldObj
            $backupResult = manage-bde -protectors -adbackup -cn $Computer c: -id $GUID
            write-host $Computer' : BITLOCKER ACTIVE '$GUID' - '$backupResult 
            }
        else
            {
            write-host $Computer' : NO BITLOCKER' 
            }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host $Computer' : UNREACHABLE' 
    }
}
```

I expect it to automatically enable bitlockker on all devices connected in active directory but instead it returns an error saying

> path not found

> $Computers = get-content "C:\ADMIN\SCRIPTS\BITLOCKER\LAPTOPS.txt"

this path...

Comment: Sounds like it can't find the text file. Or some of those directories don't exist.